# android layout: TextView on the right side of the TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I need layout that shows:

1. If *cl__tv_team_name* has short text, it shows (Q) sign next to
   *cl__tv_team_name* (*cl__tv_team_name* and (Q) sign are next to each other)
2. If *cl__tv_team_name* has long text, textview shows it with two or more lines, but (Q) sign is **still visible** on the right side

Simple `LinearLayout` doesn't work. TextView *cl__tv_team_name* takes all the width.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cl__tv_team_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="asdfa asdfasf asdf asdf asf dsafasd fads fasdf asdfsad asdf dsaf asfd safa" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/cl__tv_q_sign"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="(Q)" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I also tried `RelativeLayout` with no proper effect:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cl__tv_team_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="asdfa asdfasf asdf asdf asf dsafasd fads fasdf asdfsad asdf dsaf asfd safa" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cl__tv_team_name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cl__tv_team_name"
        android:text="(Q)"
        android:textSize="13sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `ConstraintLayout` to achieve this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="short text"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/q"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="(Q)"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/text"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/text"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Or make the text in the first view really long:

[image]

Comment: That is what I wanted to achieve. I had no time to learn Constraint Layout so thank you for your code.

Comment: One more question, Is it possible to center (Q) vertically? So it will be placed between first and second line of the first view.

Comment: Yes. Do this by constraining `q`'s top to `text`'s top, and its bottom to `text`s bottom. Remove the baseline constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Try a mixture of both Vertical Linear Layout and Horizontal Linear Layout inside the relative layout. Sounds confusing, but it generally works.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/q_sign"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="(Q)"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cl__tv_team_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/q_sign"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/q_sign"
            android:text="asdfa asdfasf asdf asdf asf dsafasd fads fasdf asdfsad asdf dsaf asfd safa" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this and when cl__tv_team_name contains short text, the (Q) sign is aligned to the right side of the container, no to the cl__tv_team_name.

Comment: Missed that requirement. Did you try using Constraint Layout?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding android:weight=1 in your LinearLayout layout xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cl__tv_team_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="asdfa asdfasf asdf asdf asf dsafasd fads fasdf asdfsad asdf dsaf asfd safa" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cl__tv_q_sign"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="(Q)" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: My bad. I missed the requirement. Your requirement seems to be bit bit tricky. But I think in RelativeLayout if you assign maxwidth to  cl__tv_team_name textview, it can work.

Comment: But I don't know maxwidth of cl__tv_team_name, that's the problem. If I knew that, the solution would be very simple ;)

Comment: You can calculate that in run time I guess. 
maxWidth =  Display.width - textview(cl__tv_q_sign).width